# Breakpoint Sass conflict

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass, breakpoint-sass

When I do **compass watch** in my project after following the instructions to install breakpoint, i get this:

```
Unable to activate breakpoint-2.4.6, because sass-3.4.23 conflicts with sass (~> 3.3.0)
```

I have no idea what I need to update and how. The installation instructions are not exactly a really well written in the first place because at least a few things have to be looked up elsewhere in order to figure out what they are saying.

I used the recommended method to install breakpoint using bundle and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like you have sass v 3.4.23 installed already and breakpoint (as of your version and the newest 2.7.1) needs sass v ~> 3.3).  Do you specify sass in your Gemfile? Or do you know what's using the newer sass gem? From this Im thinking you need to remove the newer sass and run bundle. or specify the lower sass version and bundle update.

Comment: The installation instructions said nothing about any version of Sass being too new, so I installed the latest.

Answer (score 1):

user3366016 pointed me in the correct direction. I had to uninstall compass:

```
gem uninstall compass
```

(and a prompt in my case asked to uninstall all versions) Then:

```
gem uninstall sass
```

It turned out I had the newer version installed as well as the older one that breakpoint prefers. So I just removed the newer one. Then I reinstalled compass:

```
gem install compass
```

without specifying any version at all.

It now seems to work. I hope this helps someone with the same problem.